# Installing nVidia drivers causing random coloured squares on desktop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, screen

So I have Ubuntu with an i3 desktop and it all seemed to be working accordingly, but when I install my nVidia drivers I get the following screen:

[image: Desktop]

Without the driver the screen was just black (as it is meant to be) but now it looks as above.

Interestingly if I open applications like terminal or firefox everything renders fine, it is almost as if it only happens during the initial "draw".

Has anyone came across this?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Hey @NeoTheThird yes a few times same error each time :)